# Compare two (or more) row between themselves

Tags: mysql

I want to compare two (and eventually more) row between themselves in order to know what field are identical or not.

If it is any important, my context is the following :

I have a table A and B set up so that one row of A can be referenced by one or many row of B.
If the row from table A is deleted, nothing happens to the row in B referencing it (no delete on cascade or anything).
To some extent, the informations contained in all B table's row are enough to "reconstruct" the deleted A table's row.
So we have an algorithm that does that.

What I'm doing is that I create an A row with many B row normally, and then I update A row's id so that all B row lost it.
Then I use the "reconstruct A algo" and obtain a new A row.

So, finally, I want to see what's identical and what's not, but it's difficult to do it manually because there are 200+ columns, and ALL the name's column are unreadable.
If you want to know what a column mean (and so, if losing it's value is normal or not), you have to read the column's comment.

So what I'm hoping is having a result like this for all column value that are different between the "updated" and "reconstructed" row.

Let's say I have two row like that (all name and data are fake, of course)

```
id        | cddp     | trfn | dpma              | zdra     | mawp  | tt1 | tt2       
----------+----------+------+-------------------+----------+-------+-----+------------
999999999 | 19536745 | 42   | morning : toronto | accepted | Fedex |     | /dev/null 
123784    | 00000000 | 42   | day : nothing     | accepted | TNT   |     | /dev/null
```

What I would want is having the following result

```
column_name | column_comment  | A_row_update_value | A_row_reconstructed_value
------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------------------
id          | Row identifier  | 999999999          | 123784
cddp        | Door code       | 19536745           | 00000000
dpma        | Monday planning | morning : toronto  | day : nothing
mawp        | Transporter     | Fedex              | TNT
...         | ...             | ...                | ...
```

So far, I had to do many thing from the code source.

STEP 1 : Get all column name with their comment :

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME,
    COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_A'
```

STEP 2 : Do a foreach on the result and construct a looooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnggggggg query featuring one query for each column "unioned" into one result.

```
(
    SELECT
        'PREVIOUS_RESULT_COLUMN_NAME'       AS column_name,
        'PREVIOUS_RESULT_COLUMN_COMMENT'    AS column_comment,
        table_A_updated.COLUMN_NAME         AS A_row_update_value,
        table_A_reconstructed.COLUMN_NAME   AS A_row_reconstructed_value,
    FROM 
        table_A table_A_updated,
        table_A table_A_reconstructed
    WHERE
            table_A_updated.idrow = XXXXXX
        AND table_A_reconstructed.idrow = YYYY
        AND table_A_updated.COLUMN_NAME != table_A_reconstructed.COLUMN_NAME
) UNION (

    ... the same for anoter column_name

) UNION (
    ...
```

Of course, this is quite slow, and if I add another column to know if the two row's column are identical, it's slower ..

I'm quite puzzled by how difficult it is to do what I want.
Is there some trick that can ease all this mess and speed up the whole process ?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Provide all info which is enough for to reproduce your task (see #5 and #3).

Answer (score 0):

Write the rows of A to one file; write the reconstructed rows (from B) to another file.

Use the Operating System's "diff" program to compare.